# Reusing the same function by casting, or duck typing different object types

Tags: c#, .net, casting, polymorphism, duck-typing

In a .NET application, I'm consuming two remote WCF services which both have a definition for the "same" object: `CoreService.Customer` and `ProductService.Customer`.

The "same" is deliberately put in quotes; from a namespace perspective they are two different entities. However, this is pure because of the way the services are generated/consumed. In this situation it is  is a given fact that both objects originate from the same library in the backend system.

In a specific scenario I need to extract stuff from both the object types. I have a single function which is originally built for one particular instance:

```cs
private static string _ExtractFoo(CoreService.Customer customer) {
    // removed for the sake of brevity
    return string.Empty;
}
```

What I want is actually to reuse the same operation, by providing an overload and by the ways of casting or boxing simply try to convince both compiler and runtime that this will just work (think simply [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) if you will).

The following scenario's do not work:

```cs
private static string _ExtractFoo(ProductService.Customer customer) {

    // #1 - Cast, results in error:
    //      Cannot convert type ... via a built-in conversion
    return _ExtractFoo((CoreService.Customer) customer);

    // #2 - Safe cast, results in error:
    //      Cannot convert type ... via a built-in conversion
    return _ExtractFoo(customer as CoreService.Customer);

    // #3 - Works for compiler, breaks at runtime where 'casted' is null
    dynamic d = customer;
    var casted = d as CoreService.Customer;
    return _ExtractFoo(casted);
}
```

A simple fix **that does work** is serializing to json first:

```cs
private static string _ExtractFoo(ProductService.Customer customer) {
        // awkward hack - but it blends!
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer);
        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CoreService.Customer>(serialized);

        return _ExtractFoo(deserialized);
}
```

The fact that this works makes sense, considering the properties and values of both objects are guaranteed to be a match. Albeit, this is expensive and seems quite unnecessary.

Another option would be to use an [implicit conversion operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit). However, considering the objects are service generated I'm not quite seeing how to extend both objects with an operator.

The main point is not having a debate whether or not this is best practice. Nor how to find alternatives like reusing the same shared objects between different service references. I'm quite aware of the awkwardness of this hack. It suffices to say that I find it an interesting challenge from a language perspective.

And that brings me to the actual question: is there a **more elegant way** to fool the compiler into swallowing this or, better put, making a less expensive cast/boxing between two "different but the same" objects, allowing me to reuse the `_ExtractFoo()` implementation?

**Update I -** Having the external webservice use a common interface is not an option. Also, it might be good to know that the Customer object has quite a deep hierarchy of nested properties and child objects; using something like AutoMapper, or a manual map, would be cumbersome (not to mention error prone).

**Update II -** For the sake of future reference, I attempted to explain that my problem/question is how I can modify the `_ExtractFoo()` method - or its implementation - so it can be applied to both `CoreService.Customer` and `ProductService.Customer` (taken everything above into consideration). It is definitely not intended as an open question in the sense of "please list all other alternatives", although what is provided as answer is in my opinion certainly viable as options.

Comment: Assuming you can't get both objects to implement the same interface?

Comment: Indeed, that isn't an option unfortunately.

Comment: The question seems very very broad. There's so little detail, we have to infer too much, and that leads to too many possible answers. That said, in C# "duck typing" generally means you want to use `dynamic`. The only example above where you use `dynamic`, it does not seem like you've done it correctly. The whole point of `dynamic` is to _not_ cast to a specific type, but to access named members you expect to exist. I.e. **duck typing**. As soon as you cast to some specific type, you're going to lose, because you've just moved back into the static-typed world of conventional C#.

Comment: Looking at the one answer posted, this appears to be the item previously numbered **4** and now numbered **5**.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Sorry if the question is too broad in your opinion. I've added a minimal, reproducible example of the problem, accompanied with the solutions I tried. Just saying, I'm honestly trying to make my intentions clear, for which I can't find better words than: "how can I refactor the **_ExtractFoo()** method (or its implementation) so that it applies for both `CoreService.Customer` and `ProductService.Customer` and can I use boxing/casting/ducktyping etc. for it". With that in mind, I'm happy that DavidG understood what I meant and that his answer proved to be what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, your options are:

1. Get both of the source classes to implement the same interface and pass that around instead of the concrete types. This would be the preferable option but I'm guessing not possible here.
2. Deserialize and serialize back to convert between types. You already have this code, but like you say it may be slow.
3. Use a mapping library such as [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to convert between types. This is very fast but requires you bring in an external library from Nuget (I've used AutoMapper many times)
4. Manually map the properties yourself. This would probably be the fastest code but pretty awful to write.
5. Use `dynamic` all the way down the chain, not just at the top. You lose compile time type checking, but it should be reasonably fast. For example, instead of having a function like this:

   ```
   public static string _ExtractFoo(ProductService.Customer customer)
   {
       return customer.DoSomethingExciting();
   }
   ```

   You would have this:

   ```
   public static string _ExtractFoo(dynamic customer)
   {
       return customer.DoSomethingExciting();
   }
   ```

   You could, if you wanted, add some checking to ensure that `customer` is either `ProductService.Customer` or `CoreService.Customer` if you want some safety.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG - you answered at pretty much the same time I edited the question. Can you elaborate on option 4 a bit, I don't quite understand what you mean with it?

Comment: Well where your `ExtractFoo` method takes a concrete type, change it to `dynamic` and don't cast the object before passing it in.

Comment: Solution no. 5 is exactly what I was looking for; I totally overlooked that as an option! Probably too "tunnel viewed" on getting the casting to work. Thanks.